# Custom Parameter with HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

my URLs like this

```
http://example.com/mypage.php
http://example.com/{additional_parameter}/mypage.php
```

Here, my mypage.php gets `{additional_parameter}` and works further. My mypage.php work without  `{additional_parameter}` also.

How to code this in htaccess?

**Example:** `http://example.com/user_id/mypage.php` will be rewrite to `http://example.com/mypage.php?id=user_id`

Comment: So you mean to rewrite the request on `mypage.php` for the both the above stated urls?

Comment: @SahilGulati yes. like `http://example.com/user_id/mypage.php` = `http://example.com/mypage.php?id=user_id`, if not user_id, it is also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try, I have tested it and its working fine.

> **Note:** Here I am assuming your user_id can contain `digits`, `alphabets` or `_`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([\w]+)\/mypage\.php$
RewriteRule .* /mypage.php?id=%1 [L,END,QSA]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\w\s]+)\/mypage\.php$ /mypage.php?id=$1 [L,END,QSA]
```

**Update:** 
*As OP's request url to work on either 0,1,2 or 3 parameters where he can handle its parameters sequence by his own.*

```
RewriteRule ^(([^\/]*)\/)?(([^\/]*)\/)?(([^\/]*)\/)mypage\.php$ /mypage.php?id=$2&class_id=$4&subject_id=$6 [L,END,QSA]
```

Comment: And what if user_id contains blank spaces ? Ex: `/my name/mypage.php`

Comment: @ABCatella For that you can change this to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([\w\s]+)\/mypage\.php$` It will accept space as well.
`

Comment: Now, a new problem, all css/image/js files not loading. What should I do now?

Comment: @ABCatella Though I have checked both the solutions which I have posted. But still if you have any issues , then just let me know, I will help you out. Also please share your current `.htaccess`

Comment: Yes. Working great. Now I need help in this code.
`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/mypage\.php$ /mypage.php?id=$1&class_id=$2&subject_id=$3 [L,END,QSA]`
This works only if all the parameters passed or no parameters are passed. If any one of the parameter is missed, the page gives error. I need the page to be worked even ANY one/two parameters passed.

Comment: @ABCatella Can you share an example for that..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158593/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-a-b-catella).